# is there any method to find how many task remaing in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor for some task. I need to know whether ThreadPoolExecutor has and method to find how many task remaining in assigned queue. is it possible? depends upon the return value i'll assign task again ,I don't know how many task assigned early.

Comment: You probably want to tag this with the language in question, which I suspect is Java. Also, if you'd accept answers to some of your previous questions, people would be more willing to help you with new questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ThreadPoolExecutor's getTaskCount() method to get the tasks in the queue. This is an approximate value as tasks coulld be consumed dynamically and this value can change.